# What is a uuid for in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, uuid

I came across the term `uuid` in articles about Angular directives, factories, etc. For example there is also this package on [Github](https://github.com/daniellmb/angular-uuid-service)

I can't find any explanation about what it is or what it is used for.

Can someone explain what `uuid`'s are when it comes to AngularJS?

Comment: The same as they are in any other context: Universally Unique IDentifiers: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/uuid/info

Comment: That link is a module that implements UUID (not an Angular specific concept, you can check Wikipedia). Do you have more articles that use the term in a confusing (or Angular-specific) way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a normal Universally Unique Identifier generator for AngularJs.(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)

You use UUID when you need unique identifier id for your objects etc... (for example, user id across various systems).

Comment: Take for example 2 different applications that manage accounts and you want to integrate between them. each account has ID and name. if the ID is integer than you could have the same ID both of them (id 1, name Arik in app A and id 1, name Bench in app B). if the ID wasn't integer but UUID it would have made sure that the IDs never be identical... Arik will have ID X and Bench will have ID Y. There is never same UUID in the world.

Comment: Cool, but I don't understand how their can never be a duplicate... is there a central body administering them (like a web domain name)? Nothing in the code indicates that it is checked to make sure it's not a duplicate.

Comment: I will quote from Wikipedia - "In this context the word unique should be taken to mean "practically unique" rather than "guaranteed unique". it is possible for two differing items to share the same identifier. The identifier size and generation process need to be selected so as to make this sufficiently improbable in practice. Anyone can create a UUID and use it to identify something with reasonable confidence that the same identifier will never be unintentionally created by anyone to identify something else." check this link - (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).